# Write on InnoDB read from MyIsam

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm working on a project that requires lots of database inserts.
I also need to be able to use something like full-text-search to retrieve the data.

Is is possible to use 2 tables, with the same exact data, oen MyIsam and one InnoDb to achieve this effect?

Write on the InnoDb, and somehow read off of the MyIsam?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use replication. On the "master" server use InnoDB. On the slave, change the table type to MyISAM and add the full text index. You won't have to do anything in code except insert and select from the proper servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write to both tables when writing and read from the MyISAM table when searching.

There's no way to automatically write to both tables I think, it has to be done in your application code.